# unity3d - android file reading error

Tags: c#, android, xml, unity-game-engine, uri

I have a problem with reading files on aandroid after building apk file. When I try to read data form:

*jar:file:///data/app/*appname*/base.apk!/assets/Levels/level0.xml,*

game will crush with error message: **URI scheme must start with a letter and must consist of one of alphabet, digits, '+', '-' or '.' character**.

Here is part of code that throws an exception:

```
void start()
{
        //some part of code
        level = Level.loadLevel(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath , Path.Combine("Levels", "level0.xml")));
        //some part of code
}
public static Level loadLevel(string filePath)
{
        Level result = new Level();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filePath);
        //some part of code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since files are contained inside a compressed .jar file, you have to use Unity [**WWW**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class to read them. It should look like this:

```
public IEnumerator loadLevel(string filePath)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
    yield return www;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(www.text);
    [...]
}
```

*Hope this helps,*